# Kohana ORM Relationships and Displaying Information

Tags: orm, kohana

I don't know how to approach this.

Lets say I have 3 models, A, B, and C.

Model A has many C, Model B has many C, C belongs to A and B.

I get all of B.

```
$getBs=ORM::factory('B')->find_all();
```

I display A, B, C.

```
foreach($getBs as $getB)
{
    echo $getB->b_category_title;
    foreach($getB->C->find_all() as $getC)
    {
        echo $getC->c_title;
        echo $getA->a_author; //Problem part
    }
}
```

I do not know how to access and connect Model A to Model C when displaying information for Model C.

### Edit

To get working code, I change Model A - C to Model One - Three.

Using biakaveron example of _load_with, I get the following error:

```
Database_Exception [ 1054 ]: Unknown column 'three.id_c' in 'on clause' [ SELECT `ones`.`a_id` AS `ones:a_id`, `ones`.`a_author` AS `ones:a_author`, `three`.* FROM `threes` AS `three` JOIN `twos_threes` ON (`twos_threes`.`id_c` = `three`.`c_id`) LEFT JOIN `ones` AS `ones` ON (`ones`.`a_id` = `three`.`id_c`) WHERE `twos_threes`.`id_b` = '1' ]
```

Models:

```
class Model_One extends ORM {

protected $_primary_key = 'a_id';

protected $_has_many = array(
    'threes'=> array(
        'model' => 'three',                
        'through' => 'ones_threes',   
        'far_key' => 'id_c',       
        'foreign_key' => 'id_a'   
        ),
    );
}

class Model_Two extends ORM {

protected $_primary_key = 'b_id';

protected $_has_many = array(
    'threes'=> array(
        'model' => 'three',                
        'through' => 'twos_threes',   
        'far_key' => 'id_c',       
        'foreign_key' => 'id_b'   
        ),
    );
}

class Model_Three extends ORM {

protected $_primary_key = 'c_id';

protected $_belongs_to = array(
    'ones'=> array(
        'model' => 'one',                
        'through' => 'ones_threes',    
        'far_key' => 'id_a',       
        'foreign_key' => 'id_c'   
        ),

'twos'=> array(
        'model' => 'two',                
        'through' => 'twos_threes',    
        'far_key' => 'id_b',       
        'foreign_key' => 'id_c'   
        ),
);

protected $_load_with = array('ones');
}
```

Why is it looking for three.id_c?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> C belongs to A and B.

```
foreach($getBs as $getB)
{
    echo $getB->b_category_title;
    foreach($getB->C->find_all() as $getC)
    {
        echo $getC->c_title;
        echo $getC->A->a_author; 
    }
}
```

PS. Just a note. You can load both C and A objects using `$_load_with` property:

```
class Model_C extends ORM {
    // ...
    protected $_load_with = array('A');
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Just curious how does the `_load_with` property works? Let's say table C has a relationship to table A via the column "a_id". How does Kohana match all this? Do the table and column names need to have a special format?

Comment: `$_load_with` contains just a relation alias, fully described in `$_belongs_to` property. Its the same as call `->with('A')` before loading the model.

Comment: I'm getting an error when I use the _load_with property. I added the error to my post.

Comment: Why `'foreign_key' => 'id_c' `? It should be `'foreign_key' => 'c_id' ` I think. Check your foreign key names.